# Is AWS Route 53 with GeoLocation Routing sufficient for basic CDN behavior

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, cdn, amazon-route53

The majority of my website traffic is from North America and the UK. Is it possible to "simply" use AWS Route 53 with GeoLocation routing instead of using a CDN? What I envision is deploying my app on an ELB in both North America and the UK and then have a GeoLocation routing policy in Route 53 which sends traffic to the appropriate ELB. The reasons I'd do this are to avoid the CloudFront CDN costs for a $600/month dedicated SSL... sort of a poor mans CDN.

I'd love to hear from others if this is possible, and effective.

Comment: The $600/month *dedicated* SSL feature on CloudFront is **not** needed in order to use SSL with CloudFront, and it is probably used *very rarely*.  Why do you think you need that?

Comment: I'm primarily considering SEO implications of using an SNI certificate. I know the jury is still out on whether or not SNI negatively affects SEO, but my personal experience with CloudFlare and an SNI certificate was negative... that's why I'm trying to find an alternate dedicated SSL solution that isn't $600/month.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you will like one of the products that was recently added to the AWS catalog. With the [AWS Global Accelerator](https://aws.amazon.com/global-accelerator/) you get a single IP address, and your traffic will be routed to the optimal region depending on user's location, but also on service health.

And of course you can always use the generic cloudfront domain for SSL, or a custom domain for SSL using SNI and that would be for free. You only need to pay $600 if you want a custom domain with a dedicated IP, so no SNI. Given the status of [SNI support](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication), it might be the case it's good enough for your user base.

Comment: Looks pretty cool. It's not quite the answer to my question but an alternative solution. I'll come back and accept this if it works as I am hoping.

Answer (score 0):

As of late 2021, [AWS Route 53's Geolocation Routing feature](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-policy.html#routing-policy-geo) supports this use case...

> Geolocation routing lets you choose the resources that serve your traffic based on the geographic location of your users, meaning the location that DNS queries originate from. For example, you might want all queries from Europe to be routed to an ELB load balancer in the Frankfurt region.